# Select Count between tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm brand new to SQL, and a little lost on using SELECT. I have two tables: table1 has two columns with a name and unique integer identifier (e.x. 'Dave', 998); table2 has one relevant column, which repeats that same identifier (multiple instances of 998).

I want to run a query to go through every row in table1 and count / SELECTevery instance of that unique integer in table 2. (e.g. if there are 3 instances of Dave's 998 number, I want SELECT to output column1: 'Dave', column2: 3) This would be the equivalent elsewhere of a simple CountIf, which might be part of my problem--I'm stuck on Python and still struggling to adjust.

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using?  SQL is just a language, but doesn't tell us which exact tool you are using.

Comment: I'm using MySQL; apologies, I thought SQL made most tools pretty synonymous.

Comment: They do, but not exactly the same.  In this case, it doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple join/count query should work here:

```
SELECT
    t1.name,
    t1.id,
    COUNT(t2.id) AS cnt
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY
    t1.name,
    t1.id;
```

Note that we left join and count `table2.id` here, because in the case where an `id` in the first table matches to nothing, it would correctly report a count of zero.

Comment: Thank you, this is hugely helpful--working through it one line at a time to try and understand it and make sure I get where I went wrong. I think I was really misunderstanding the use of JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

You will need two basic but powerful concepts of SQL to get your desired result. No matter what database engine and what version, its inherently supported in all relational databases afaik): `JOIN` & `Aggregation`(`count` with `group by`) .

```
select t1.name, count(t2.id)
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.name;
```

Comment: Thank you! Between just these two replies I learned more about how this works in 15 minutes than in the last 5 hours. Perfect.

Comment: Glad was able to help.